# How to fetch desired elements out of every inner List?

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, dictionary

I have a data stored in List, which is List of objects.

I need to traverse through every inner list and check if object satisfy the condition then store it in other List.

```
public class Data //class that actually holds data
{
    public string DataPart;
    public string Category;
    public Data (string dataPart, string category)
    {
        this.DataPart = dataPart;
        this.Category = category;
    }
}
```

Data structure in which data is stored is like below:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Data>>
```

Sample code showing my current solution:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Data>> dataTbl = new Dictionary<int, List<Data>>();

//initializing the data structure
List<Data> lst1 = new List<Data>();
lst1.Add(new Data("data1OfLst1", "cat1"));
lst1.Add(new Data("data2OfLst1", "cat2"));
lst1.Add(new Data("data3Oflst1", "cat3"));
dataTbl.Add(1, lst1);
List<Data> lst2 = new List<Data>();
lst2.Add(new Data("data1OfLst2", "cat1"));
lst2.Add(new Data("data2OfLst2", "cat2"));
lst2.Add(new Data("data3Oflst2", "cat3"));
dataTbl.Add(2, lst2);

List<Data> cat1Data = new List<Data>();
foreach(List<Data> datList in dataTbl.Values)
{
    if(datList.Any( x => x.Category == "cat1"))
        cat1Data.Add(datList.Where(x => x.Category == "cat1").FirstOrDefault());
}
```

But the number of records in Dictionary and the number of elements in every record's `List` will be a big number. Thus I'm looking for better solution.

***Note that it is possible that some of record in `Dictionary` may not contain any such data which satisfy the condition (here `"cat1"` check). final list should not contain `null` values***

EDIT:

It is general assumption (not a die-hard validation) that there should be only one (or no) entry of particular category in inner list, so there will be no inner lists which contain more than one objects with `"cat1"`.

Comment: If you already have a working solution, you should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Nevertheless: what do you consider to be "better"? Performance-wise? Memory-wise? Less numbers of code?

Comment: @HimBromBeere performance-wise. and yes, next time in such cases i'll ask question there.

Comment: If thinking about performance you should use a profiler to indicate if you even *have* a performance-problem and if this is caused by this code. Or in other words: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: if you are thinking in terms of perfromance then for loop is any time better than linq query and may be try out parallel linq but you have to check performance by your self

Comment: @HimBromBeere  thanks. better I should run profiler on both the solution.

Comment: Given the answers below, you should clarify what to do with 2 "cat1" in one list.

Comment: Yes, that helps but also prompts the next question: How often do you add/Remove items? Because it could be beneficial to maintain a `<"cat", Data>` dictionary in parallel.

Comment: here item is being added every minute. and items being removed at particular time in a day (so once in a day)

Comment: If this query is executed way more than Adding, keeping that 2nd Dictionary might pay. It would be a `<string, List<Data>>` and give you the answer instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I´ve already told in the comment, you shopuldn´t bother for faster code as long as you didn´t use a profiler to indicate **if** you even have a performance-problem and **if** so, **if** this is caused by your code or some other you don´t think of. You see: there are many if´s.

Apart from this I have some smarter code for you, which won´t be much faster - if at all, but easier to read and thus to maintain, which should be your **primary goal**, everything else is just hunting for nano-seconds.

```
List<Data> cat1Data = new List<Data>();
foreach(List<Data> datList in dataTbl.Values)
{
    var el = datList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Category == "cat1");
    if(el != null)
        cat1Data.Add(el);
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` will return the default-value (`null` for reference-types, for struct-types the structs default-value). In fact you´re checking the same thing two times.

So you don´t need to check if there is an element satisfying your condition in the current list select this element again afterwards. Instead directly search for it and add it if found.

Comment: I got your point, I could figure it out that I m checking for "cat1" more than required (+1) for that. but i could sense only two times (so one more time than required), can you tell me how it is checking the thing third time?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using Dictionary only when your indexes have a special meaning besides just positional placement. In your case you may create a list of list objects.

```
 public class MainClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and then replace your code with

```
        MainClass dataTbl = new MainClass();
        List<Data> lst1 = new List<Data>();
        lst1.Add(new Data("data1OfLst1", "cat1"));
        lst1.Add(new Data("data2OfLst1", "cat2"));
        lst1.Add(new Data("data3Oflst1", "cat3"));
        dataTbl.Id = 1;
        dataTbl.Data = lst1;

        List<Data> lst2 = new List<Data>();
        lst2.Add(new Data("data1OfLst2", "cat1"));
        lst2.Add(new Data("data2OfLst2", "cat2"));
        lst2.Add(new Data("data3Oflst2", "cat3"));
        dataTbl.Id = 2;
        dataTbl.Data = lst2;

        List<Data> cat1Data = new List<Data>();

        cat1Data = dataTbl.Data.Where(i => i.Category.Contains("cat1")).ToList();
```

Contains will ensure that you have data with category as only "cat1" and won't contain any null values.

Do try and let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: that's really revolutionary suggestion! actually this collection is widely used in entire cache management of project. using Dictionary is intentional and conscience decision because easiness of using it and speed it provides in fetching any single key-value pair out of hundreds of records.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this , and get all the records with `cat1`

```
var list = dictionary.Values              // To get just the List<Data>s
                     .SelectMany(x => x)  // Flatten
                     .Where(x => x.Category == "cat1")
                     .ToList();           // Listify
```

or

```
var list = dictionary.SelectMany(x => x.Value)  // Flatten
                     .Where(x => x.Category == "cat1")
                     .ToList();           // Listify
```

---

for performance try out parallel linq , this make use of multiple thread but suggest compare with without parallel performance and use it

```
var list = dictionary.Values.AsParallel() // To get just the List<Data>s
                     .SelectMany(x => x)  // Flatten
                     .Where(x => x.Category == "cat1")
                     .ToList();           // Listify
```

**Note :** make use of For Loop if you really care about performance, remove all linq code that you tried better just make use of forloop only

Comment: I think you overlooked  the FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @HenkHolterman - if you see his data he dont need it as its having only on record for each category , and if he want to avoid duplication he can use `Distinct()`

Comment: "his data" is just a sample (but the OP should clarify). Distinct() after-the-fact isn't the same logic as one-per-Dictionary item.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree with Pranay, although the OP asked for `null` checking, his sample data doesn't require it. And since his goal is performance, then there is no point in adding redundant checking. This answers the question perfectly. If the sample data is incorrect, then that's a problem with the question not the answer.

Comment: Why do you think the sample data is leading?  That kind of thinking costs our industry so many billions each year.

Comment: Well, that's *"so many billions each year"* in our pockets :). We're programmers, not fortune tellers. We don't create requirements, we just gather them. If the requirements are wrong, that's not our mistake. Sure we can argue them and discuss what we think is possibly incorrect, but once this process of requirement gathering is done, the app is built upon the assumption that they are correct. It's the client's responsibility to re-evaluate them during User-Testing and then we can adjust. The main requirement in this question is **Performance**.

Comment: But I asked and now we have better requirements and your (and Pranay's) solution is correct but sub-optimal.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - and i already written in comment of question that you should use for loop intead of linq query to get better performance.. i dont know why you put -1 on my answer

Comment: "use of forloop only" - yes, I did put +1 on that answer. The interesting part of this answer is the `AsParallel` but that needs profiling.

Comment: Also, `.Values.SelectMany(x => x)` can/should be `.SelectMany(x => x.Value)`. Depending on the Dictionary yours could be slower.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - havent tried that but trust you on that, so it should be `dictionary.SelectMany(x => x.Value)` ?? that will not work ..as are are already on values

Comment: *your (and Pranay's) solution is correct*, so why the -1? :) And do you see now that your argument was baseless? :P. As for `sub-optimal`, that depends on how many milliseconds you care to save. I tested it Pranay's answers against HimBromBeere's answer and they were very close, so save a couple more milliseconds or have a nicer code, only OP can decide. As for `AsParallel`, that didn't make a difference in my test, but the OP needs to profile it with his real code.

Comment: @RacilHilan - thanks , let see its happend differnce of opnion , i answered first when there is no much details added though i updated according to my knowldege and input given by OP

Comment: @PranayRana Yes, I think having different options is a good thing, so the OP can try them and choose what they think is the best for their project. You probably won't recover the -1, but +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the collections without flattening first and then remove the any nulls caused by the `FirstOrDefault` at the end:

```
dataTbl.Values
       .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Category == "cat1"))
       .Where(x=>x != null);
```

Comment: is it better then what pranay has suggested? if yes, can you explain how ?

Comment: Better could be a subjective measure. They both give the same result, my suggestion avoids traversing every element twice, the SelectMany will traverse the list then the Where filters the flat list, a second traversal. You could leave the `Where` clause off the end of this if your data determined it wasn't required

Comment: I also tested all three options against a set with 1,000,000 members which included values which didn't match the predicate and found this was faster

Comment: Hmmm, in my test, your answer performed a little slower than Pranay's answer. I wonder why our tests have different results :(. However, the difference is not big, so if the null checking is really required (the sample data doesn't need it), then this answer is better regardless of the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking the condition twice inside a loop? That's like doing the same thing 3 times. Just select directly to your list based on the condition. No need for a loop and no need for first check:

```
List<Data> cat1Data = dataTbl.Values
                             .SelectMany(x => x)
                             .Where(x => x.Category == "cat1")
                             .ToList();
```

As HenkHolterman mentioned, it can be also written like this:

```
List<Data> cat1Data = dataTbl.SelectMany(x => x.Value)
                             .Where(x => x.Category == "cat1")
                             .ToList();
```

The results are identical, but the performance may vary a bit.

Comment: my answer is same as yours not diff in this

Comment: @PranayRana Yes, I'm sorry for that. I've just realized it after posting. But I have a good explanation and using the real object name `dataTbl` instead of your incorrect `dictionary`. Add a similar explanation and fix the name of the object and I will delete my answer.