# Select n Items from the Child List?

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

how can I get N elements of the child list? Let's say I'd like to get 2 children for each parent.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<Parent>()
        {
            new Parent()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "ParentName1",
                Children = new List<Child>()
                {
                    new Child() { Id = 1, Name = "ChildName1"},
                    new Child() { Id = 2, Name = "ChildName2"},
                    new Child() { Id = 3, Name = "ChildName3"},
                    new Child() { Id = 4, Name = "ChildName4"},
                    new Child() { Id = 5, Name = "ChildName5"},
                }
            },
            new Parent()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "ParentName2",
                Children = new List<Child>()
                {
                    new Child() { Id = 6, Name = "ChildName6"},
                    new Child() { Id = 7, Name = "ChildName7"},
                    new Child() { Id = 8, Name = "ChildName8"},
                    new Child() { Id = 9, Name = "ChildName9"},
                    new Child() { Id = 10, Name = "ChildName10"},
                }
            }
        };

        // Get only 2 child elements for parent
        var filteredData = data.Where(x => x.Children.Count >= 2)
            .ToList();


        foreach (var filteredParent in filteredData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Parent {filteredParent.Id} with {filteredParent.Children.Count} children.");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `data.SelectMany(x => x.Children.Take(2))`

Comment: Try `var filteredData = data.Where(x => x.Children.Count >=2).SelectMany(x => x); `

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @user3261186: That's an answer, not a comment. It's also not what the OP is asking. They're not asking for the _entire_ list of children if there's more than two children; they're asking for the first two children of each list.

Comment: @Flater Actually, I think Slava's comment is also not what the OP is looking for. If you'll notice the foreach loop in code in the question, You'll see that the OP is looking to get the parents, but filter out all the children except the first 2 of each parent.

Comment: you may want to read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914179/how-to-fetch-desired-elements-out-of-every-inner-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a multi statement lambda expression for the result selector and `List<T>`'s `RemoveRange` method:

```
var query = data.Select
(
    p => 
    {
        p.Children.RemoveRange(2, p.Children.Count - 2); 
        return p;
    }
);
```

As Flater commented, It might be better to return a shallow copy of the parent, with only the first two children. That way your query does not change the source data:

```
var query = data.Select
(
    p => new Parent() 
        {
            Id = p.Id, 
            Name = p.Name, 
            Children = p.Children.Take(2).ToList()
        }
);
```

Comment: Why run the risk of creating bugs by modifying the source list, as opposed to doing `Take(2)` which yields the same result without modifying data that is possibly used elsewhere?

Comment: @Flater Edited.

Comment: To extend your answer, it might be relevant to note that the OP could also _not_ reform the list, and simply use `Children.Take(2)` wherever he would otherwise reference the `Children` property (e.g. in a foreach: `foreach(var child in myParent.Children.Take(2))`. This means you don't have to make a copy (which would require you to define all fields you wish to copy, which may lead to a lot of trivial code and/or maintenance issues down the line).